# Using AWK to parse from XML

Tags: shell-script, awk, xml

I need just the first instance of an ANSI formatted date (YYYY-MM-DD) from the string shown below.

```
PosMntReq ReqId="XXXXX" TxnTyp="4" Actn="1" BizDt="2019-03-27" TxnTm="2019-03-27T10:41:13" AdjTyp="3" SetSesID="EOD">
```

The command I wrote with awk does not provide the date

```
v_business_date=$(awk -F= 'NR==4 { print $5}' XMLCD02)

bash-4.2$ echo $v_business_date
"2019-03-27" TxnTm
```

The line with the date will be in the file many times; I want the first occurrence of this line.

Comment: Are you parsing an XML file?

Comment: Yes..This is an XML file.

Comment: Then you'll want to use an XML parser. [tag:xmlstarlet] is a good choice for command line work. This simplifies your work to extract value, as you basically just need the XPath to that attribute.

Comment: This Stack Overflow page provides guidance on how to ask a good question: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

Making some assumptions about your data:

```
$ cat file.xml
<root>
  <node1>
    <node2 ReqId="XXXXX" TxnTyp="4" Actn="1" BizDt="2019-03-27" TxnTm="2019-03-27T10:41:13" AdjTyp="3" SetSesID="EOD"> 
    </node2>
  </node1>
</root>

$ txn_tm=$( xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//node2/@TxnTm' file.xml )

$ echo "$txn_tm"
2019-03-27T10:41:13
```

If you want to select the node based on the ReqId, then we need to adjust the xpath: return the "TxnTm" attribute value for any node with the specified "ReqId" attribute.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//*[@ReqId = "XXXXX"]/@TxnTm' -n file.xml
```

Comment: It's likely that they want to use `ReqId` in the selection.

Comment: Argh, not seen that was XML :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions to parse XML.  That way lies madness.  But if you insist on a descent into madness and ponies:

```
sed -En '/TxnTm=/{s/^.*TxnTm="//;s/T[0-9:]+".*$//;p;q;}' < inputfile
```

Comment: well above command is printing all occurrences of date whereas I want to print it only once.

Comment: @user313150 Please update the question with a complete and well formed XML document. You only gave us a partial snippet. We have no way of knowing what the rest of the document looks like or if there are more date attributes elsewhere.

Comment: This works for the example input given.  If that input was insufficient to advise the answer, this is a case of GIGO, and also a case of _don't parse XML with regular expressions_.

Comment: I have edited the command to stop at the first match.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler option using just `grep`, albeit again with the advisory that using regular expression tools to parse XML or XHTML is a one-way ticket to sadness-town:

```
$ grep -m1 -oE '"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"' input
"2019-03-27"
```